# Open-source java XSLT 2.0 implementation?

Tags: java, xml, open-source, xslt-2.0, xslt

I'm currently looking into using XSLT 2.0, but I cannot find any open-source java implementations ([Saxon-B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxon_XSLT) seems to fit the bill, but isn't schema-aware).

Am I missing something?

Comment: Search or ask this question at the [xsl-list](http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/). Michael Kay might answer himself.

Comment: 5 years later and there still is no open source Schema-aware, XSLT 2.0, and XPath 2.0 processor? Dang...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only one is Saxon-HE:

[Saxon-HE](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/)

The W3C hosts an online version of it for testing:

[W3C Jigsaw XSLT 2.0 Service](http://www.w3.org/2005/08/online_xslt/)

And there is JSFiddle like version as well:

[xsltransform.net](http://xsltransform.net/)

And the Frameless project hosts a JavaScript version of it:

[XSLT Fiddle](http://fiddle.frameless.io/)

There's also an App Engine project which uses it:

[XSLT App Engine Test Harness](https://xslttest.appspot.com/)

Other than that, there's an incomplete Xerces extension which implements XPath 2.0:

[Xerces XPath 2.0 Extension](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xsltproc/)

An Eclipse extension which implements XPath 2.0:

[WTP XPath2.0 Processor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/PsychoPathXPathProcessor)

An incomplete Xalan-J branch which partially implements XSLT 2.0:

> Some prototype work for XSLT 2.0 
>   support in the Xalan-J Interpretive processor went on in 2003, but then 
>   trailed off.  That prototype work is still available on the xslt20 branch 
>   http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/xalan/java/branches/xslt20/, but since 
>   then nobdy has stepped forward to carry on that initial prototyping, and 
>   the Xalan PMC hasn't put in place any plans for XSLT 2.0 support.

As well as a server-side implementation of [Saxon-CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml) which can run on [Nashorn/Avatar.js](https://avatar-js.java.net/):

[xslty](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xslty)

**References**

- [Running Node.js on Java 8 Nashorn with Avatar.js on Windows "no avatar-js in java.library.path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23130587/running-node-js-on-java-8-nashorn-with-avatar-js-on-windows-no-avatar-js-in-jav)
- [Re: Xalan-J XSLT 2.0 status](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/xml-xalan-dev/200608.mbox/<OF9710600B.492097BF-ON852571D3.00577829-852571D3.0057BE5E@ca.ibm.com>)
- [org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.sdk.feature](http://git.eclipse.org/c/sourceediting/webtools.sourceediting.xpath.git/tree/features/org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.sdk.feature/feature.properties)
- [Nashorn - The Combined Power of Java and JavaScript in JDK 8](http://www.infoq.com/articles/nashorn)
- [Nodyn Completion of the Node.js API](http://nodyn.io/compatibility.html)
- [Saxonica Product Feature Matrix](http://www.saxonica.com/html/products/feature-matrix-9-6.html)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I'm answering my own question from 2.5 years ago:

I haven't tried it yet, but I just stumbled upon [Eclipse PsychoPath](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.wst.xml.xpath2.processor.doc.user/html/index.html), which is (according to the docs) a XPath 2.0 XML Schema Aware processor that passes 96% of the XPath 2.0 test suite (version 1.1M1).

Comment: In the question you ask for an XSLT 2.0 processor. But this answer is about an XPath 2.0 processor.

Comment: Thanks for catching this, mzjn. I was actually looking for both, and got them mixed up. 
I've removed the accepted answer flag from my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the archive, there's also [AltovaXML](http://www.altova.com/altovaxml.html), the free-as-in-beer, schema-aware XSLT 2.0 engine used in XMLSpy etc.

Unfortunately, like XMLSpy, it's Windows only.

Comment: It appears this is now called Raptor-XML and no longer open source.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you *really* need a schema aware processor? It might help find errors in the stylesheets quicker but the cost might outweigh the benefit (both in terms of money, and license-wise).

Saxon-SA is the schema-aware version of Saxon B. It includes the open source Saxon B in full (published under the Mozilla Public License). It's only the "schema-aware" stuff which is closed source, so most of it is still free software (though only as in free speech..).

Comment: Well, I work with namespaces a lot when implementing web services, and cannot pretend they wouldn't exist..

I know about Saxon-SA and Saxon-B, but was wondering if there really is no open source alternative. Especially since XSLT 2.0 isn't exactly brand new..

Comment: Sad, but true that I haven't yet found one.  And the Oracle I've used (proprietary) is not good either.  Hope somebody comes thru